# VLFeat HOG feature extraction

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction

I found a tutorial about VLFeat HOG

```
http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/hog.html
```

I am a little confused by the 16*16*31 matrix. Can anyone tell me how can I extract features that can be used for classification task from the matrix that the function returns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The entries in that matrix *are* features! Depending on what you're trying to achieve you might do some dimensionality reduction or augmentation or post processing, but none of that is strictly necessary. Check out [the original HoG paper](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf).